# Facebook application open graph actions in non-english language

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I have Facebook application that has non English native language, but when I create and use open graph actions and objects they appear English. I can not change action texts to my native language because it does not accept my characters and because native language is not english I can not translate it.

How can I use and see open graph actions and objects in my native language?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your app settings page under https://developers.facebook.com/apps/, edit your app settings – on the left you should find a link saying „translate your app” (or something similar, I'm currently using the german interface), it's currently the second link from bottom.

And https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/ explains the whole process.